# What should I know before buying a Labrador puppy in India?

Tags: dogs, certificate

I am thinking of buying / adopting a Labrador puppy in Hyderabad, India. However, I know that getting a pet is a huge emotional investment, more than anything else. I would like to know what I should be ready for when I am ready to buy one:

1. How can I verify whether the pup is a pure breed (a pure lab) and not a crossbreed?
2. Is there any vaccination and other tests which need to be carried out on the pup before it's ready for purchase?
3. Should I be looking for a KCI (Kennel Club of India) certification of the pup before buying it?
4. What accessories should I buy for the pup at the time of purchase?

Comment: There is a fifth point to ask: What other than accessories does a puppy need? Time, space, training and companionship for example.

Comment: I assume your question is a very broad one. It would suit more to the conventions of this site, to make each question an own post. You can link the questions to each other, so the scope and context will be known, and you do not need to explain it again and again. I will help to link, if you wish so.

Comment: @Allerleirauh Sure. Please do so if you feel this would make it more easy for the readers. I was thinking that it would be more easy to relate if all the points were in one question.

Comment: If I do so, I will get possible reputation points for your questions. You should do it yourself :) Then I will edit your questions and add the links